# Two questions regarding setting up a podcast with Behringer 1202fx mixer and a dual channel compressor limiter gate

Tags: podcast

I would like to know what is the proper way to connect the mixer to the compressor limiter gate to my Behringer1202fx mixer? any ideas?

Also, I would like to know if anyone has or knows how to set up at least one Skype call with  mix-minus into the same 1202 mixer.

Ideas much appreciated, Thanks in advance

Silas

Comment: Is that a separate hardware compressor/limiter/gate device or is that integrated in your 1202fx's onboard effects?

Comment: No it is separate Bob. I think I figured it out, I'm waiting on my cables to get here. I ordered them online instead of getting raped at Radio Shack. 2nd computer headphone out to Channel 3 on mixer, FX turned full left, FX send out to 2nd computer mic input.

Comment: Then main Out from mixer to CGL input on channel 1, out of CGL into a digital recorder then into 1st computer mic input. Out from 1st computer headphone jack into channel 4 on mixer for additional sound effects. Control OUT on mixer to monitor speakers. Microphones are on channels 1 & 2 of mixer. I think this should work , if any one sees something wrong with this set up Please let me know, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have the 1204USB for a while a ended up throwing out the USB adapter and getting a Saffire PRO 24 Firewire interface. This mixer and the 1202 are great but if I had the chance I would have gotten the Mackie Onyx 1220i which has the Firewire built in.

However I did manage to make the mix minus work with this desk. You need to listen and monitor from the desk but record from the computer. Next you bring the audio back into the desk via the line out of the comp and into the 7/8 channel of the desk. Leave the POT panned down and listen to the the channel in PRE and make sure you live monitoring is also playing out the PRE to the headphones (PRE never goes out to main). Looking at the PDF for the deck: http://www.behringer.com/assets/1002FX_P0572_M_EN.pdf  I'm not sure if the 1202 has PRE setting but without it, you will not be able to do this.